# How to filter out input elements with empty value and no value attribute at all?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery function that submits a search form and disables empty fields so they won't get submitted with the form and consequently won't get added to the query string in the URL:

```
$('form#search a#submit').on('click', function(event) {
    $('input').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; }).prop('disabled', true);
    $('form#search').submit();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem is, however, that the default options of my `select` boxes don't even have `value` attributes at all and thus get submitted with the form every single time, even though they are empty.

How can I get the above function to work with input elements that don't have `value` attributes as well?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you can do like $('input,select').filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not selected the selectbox in your selector, do this on line no 2

```
 $('input,select').filter(function() { return $(this).val() == ""; }).prop('disabled', true);
```